# What is a binary relation and transitive closure?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, definition, relations

-Self studying 2Yr Undergraduate Discrete Math

-Background: Calculus 3, probability 1, statistics 1, linear algebra 1, ODEs 1, stochastics 1

---

Hi, I'm studying relations and want to confirm I understand binary relations. I learned that a relation $aRb$ (let's say the relation is a is a child of b) is the Cartesian product $A\times B$, fair enough.
So mentally I draw two circles, one for set $A$, one for set $B$, and I can put a pair $(a,b)$ in a third circle $A \times B$ if the $a$ is indeed a child of $b$.

The definition of a binary relation I have here is:

"A binary relation R on A is a relation between A and A, and a binary relation can
always be composed with itself. Its inverse is a binary relation on the same set."

I tend to use visuals to help me understand, but here is where my drawing breaks down. Using the child-parent relationship again, I have a circle $A$ and I can move two a's $(a_1, a_2)$ if $a_1$ is indeed the child of $a_2$, right? The problem with this example is I can't see the significance/specialty of a binary relation.

---

REMOVED - DISREGARD BOTTOM HALF OF QUESTION

---

Second part to my question: it goes on to define a transitive closure
$$
R^* = R^0 \times R^1 \times\dots R^n
$$
as well as positive transitive closure
$$
R^+ = R^1 \times R^2 \times\dots R^n
$$
I don't understand the $R^0$ relation; I read that it's the domain of $R$ (also called an identity relation) but going back to my visual example, isn't the domain of my circle $A$ just $A$? So much like multiplying by $1$ or multiplying a matrix by $I$, is this just a fancy way to say essentially nothing? What are some applications of these two things $R^*, R^+ $?

Sorry for the long question. Pls ELI5 since I'm self studying, I don't have a teacher for this stuff :)

Comment: Please keep the body of the question to be as relevant to the question as possible.

Comment: Yeah not sure what that definition is. the transitive closure of a binary relation R on a set X is the smallest relation on X that contains R and is transitive.

Comment: A binary relation, call it $\sim$ is a subset $R$ of $A\times A$ where $a\sim b$ if $(a,b) \in R$ kind of reiterating the same thing but it's important to think of a relation as being a subset instead of being an 'operator' as we normally think of it

Comment: "So mentally I draw two circles, one for set A, one for set B, and I can put a pair (a,b) in a third circle A×B if the a is indeed a child of b." Yes and no... You cannot "remove" $a$ and $b$ from the original sets. First comment: $A$ and $B$ are the **same** set: the set of *humans* and a pair $(a,b)$ is related iff $a$ is the child of $b$. But every child has only one father, while a father may have zero or more than one children; this means that we may have $(a_1,b)$ as well as $(a_2,b)$ in the relation.